# Customising Packages on ROS Tutorial Issue

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ubuntu, package.xml, ubuntu-xenial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am very new to ROS & Ubuntu and am working through the OS tutorials.

Specifically, I am currently creating and customising my own packages (see link below for tutorial I am currently referencing, I am currently on section 6 (customising my package).

http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/CreatingPackage

I am using ROS Kinetic & Ubuntu16.04 LTS.

In section 6.1.1 I am trying to add a description tag, but I am confused how to.

The instructions are as follows:

6.1.1 description tag

First update the description tag:

> The beginner_tutorials package

Note: Change the description to anything you like, but by convention the first sentence should be short while covering the scope of the package. If it is hard to describe the package in a single sentence then it might need to be broken up.

I have tried to enter a one word description of the package but get an error.

So my description is as follows:

> jamescoady@jamescoady-Inspiron-5579:~$ The beginner_tutorials package

I then get the error:

> bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

When I remove < & > from my line I still get an error.

> jamescoady@jamescoady-Inspiron-5579:~$ rostutorialThe beginner_tutorials package /rostutorial

I then get the error:

> rostutorial: command not found

What am I doing wrong? I know this is probably a very basic error on my behalf and I do apologise if it is an awfully stupid question!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/351468/customising-packages-on-ros-tutorial-issue/) by [jimc91](https://answers.ros.org/users/45049/jimc91/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2020-05-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The manifest (that's what `package.xml` is called) is a plain XML file, which is essentially just text.

So to "update the description tag", you *open the file* in a text editor (of your choice), edit the text you want to change, save the file and close the editor.

There are no commands to run here.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-05-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sassenach6868](https://answers.ros.org/users/69993/sassenach6868/) on 2021-02-13**:
Some else had recommended using gedit package.xml to do the editing.  I ran that script and a texteditor opened, but no text appeared.  Any thoughts?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-02-13**:
Have you made sure to run it in the directory which contains the `package.xml`? If you don't, `gedit` will assume you're trying to create a new file -- with the name `package.xml` -- and will show an empty editor.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not a command.

You are expected to edit the respective file (`package.xml`) with a text editor.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2020-05-05

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1